# DB Row length/complexity vs Row count: is there a rationale for the former?

Tags: database, database-normalization

We have a db table that I'll call TIMES.  It has traditionally looked something like this:

```
ID    Blah1 Blah2 Blah3  Description
1     a     b     c      Day
2     d     e     f      Night
```

(I've added the Blah columns primarily to show that there are a lot more columns in the table which exist, but are not directly relevant to the upgrade we're trying to make.)

We want to add some language support to the results we get from the db.  So my suggestion was to either:

a) Take the lazy road and just add a new column for language, giving us

```
ID    Blah1 Blah2 Blah3  Description  Language
1     a     b     c      Day          English
2     d     e     f      Night        English
1     a     b     c      Tag          German
2     d     e     f      Nacht        German
```

or, preferably, b) do some normalization and create a new table of just the relevant values:

```
ID      Description  Language
1       Day          English
2       Night        English
1       Tag          German
2       Nacht        German
```

Our DB guy said, well, we could just use the original table and just include everything in xml...that way we'll save on rows.

```
ID        Blah1 Blah2 Blah3  Language
1         a     b     c      <TimeDescriptions>
                                 <TimeDescription language='English'>
                                     Day
                                 </TimeDesciption>
                                 <TimeDescription language='German'>
                                     Tag
                                 </TimeDesciption>
                             </TimeDescriptions>        
2         d     e     f      <TimeDescriptions>
                                 <TimeDescription language='English'>
                                     Night
                                 </TimeDesciption>
                                 <TimeDescription language='German'>
                                     Nacht
                                 </TimeDesciption>
                             </TimeDescriptions>
```

"Save on rows"?  I'm not really a db guy, but that sounds weird to me.  Sure, it will save some rows...but is that a win overall, when the rows themselves are much longer?  (Very possible)  Beyond that, it looks like it breaks rules of normalization that I'm used to.  I also know that one can use XML in SQL and search it (though I've not done it, and am very hazy on the details), but I just don't see the win with this.

He started getting prickly when I was asking about it, so I backed off, but I'd still like to know if I'm missing something.  Obviously many details are missing, but I'm not looking for a detailed analysis...I'd just like to know if it possible that this is reasonable.

EDIT: ARGH.  You would think that I've been here long enough to have learned to format correctly, but I'm messing that last bit up somehow...I'll try to fix it, but other edits are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> Sure, it will save some rows...but is that a win overall, when the
>   rows themselves are much longer?

Possibly. But that means fewer rows fit in a page, which usually means more disk accesses and more disk I/O.  Those rows don't *look* too bad now, but if you support a dozen languages, you're looking at maybe 1Kb per row for XML data alone. My rule of thumb for rough calculations is to use 8Kb per page (which can be adjusted sometimes, depending on your dbms), so you get only 8 rows per page.

Also, it means querying rows using a clause like `WHERE Description = 'Day'` is much harder. (This might not matter in your application, though.) Also, with the existing structure, you could partition the table on "Language" if you needed to.

Adding a new column to the original table *seems* to introduce a multi-valued dependency, which would violate 4NF. (Language->>Description) But if you can model it as a compound attribute, you can make that dependency go away.

**Compound attribute**: A compound attribute is an attribute that has internal structure that the dbms either a) ignores completely or b) provides functions and operators so users can manipulate the pieces. The most common example is a column of type "date". Dates have internal structure--year, month, day. They have internal multi-valued dependencies. But the dbms provides functions and operators to get at the pieces when you need them.

Your dbms might use some combination of the words *compound*, *composite*, *user-defined*, *type*, *column*, and *attribute* to describe this feature.

If your dbms supports user-defined types, you might be able to create a type for locale-specific words, and use that in a table.

But in any case, this shouldn't be a matter of opinion. You ought to be able to test a 5NF approach with surrogate keys, 5NF without surrogate keys, 5NF with compound or user-defined types, and XML in just one afternoon or one day. Then spend another afternoon making sure your indexing and querying is done well, so that performance differences aren't simply due to mistakes or hurrying or ignorance.

Finally, weigh the best performers against the cost of maintenance. (And update your CV with these newly acquired skills.)